# Windows form c# identificar qual botão do BindingNavigator foi clicado

Tags: c#, winforms

Como identificar qual opção (Add new, Delete e etc) foi escolhida em um `BindingNavigator` e qual método utilizar para capturar o clique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem a pergunta... mas se você estiver usando o Visual Studio, basta dar um duplo clique sobre o botão desejado do `BindingNavigator` que ele vai criar e associar um método ao evento do botão automaticamente.

Por exemplo: você pode dar um duplo clique sobre o botão AddNewItem, que será criado o método `bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click` que será associado ao evento `Click` do mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método do evento gerado para o clique do botão `AddNewItem`:

```
private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Para associar ao evento click do botão `DeleteItem` o procedimento é análogo.

Comment: Obrigado! Era o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

O componente `BindingNavigator` possui vários itens, esses itens possuem propriedades e eventos individuais, por exemplo, se você clicar no item que tem um `+` e for na paleta *Properties*, você verá as propriedades e eventos disponíveis, assim como você faz em um `Button` normal.

Comment: Obrigado por complementar a resposta.